# Can't update ThemeKit, "Access is denied"

Tags: command-line, themes, shopify, updates, liquid

So I've been using ThemeKit to build a Shopify theme and I've been getting a notification in the command-line window that ThemeKit has an upgrade available. It says to use `theme update` as the command to run to get this done but when I do I get this error message, `Could not update and had to roll back. open C:\Program Files\Theme Kit\.theme.exe.new: Access is denied.` Anyone else have this issue? I'm working on Windows 10 if that helps...

Comment: Try it with `cmd` (Command Prompt) but with administrator privileges (open as administrator) and try running `theme update` in there.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, that did the trick :-) I also found this article that said the same thing... ttps://appuals.com/fix-unable-to-terminate-process-access-is-denied/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @drip, for the solution, which was to open up the command prompt as administrator and then running `theme update`. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSL, it would be `sudo theme update`, then put your WSL password and it's done.